# why foreach loop generates duplicate values?

Tags: javascript, html, polarion

From the below table i want to get data.all values i m getting but the second foreach loop generates duplicate values for the fields  inside the loop

Please let me know any suggestion

```
 <div><table class="stt">
    <thead>
    <tr class="shade">
    <th>Dep Ver</th>
    <th >Order In Document Version</th>
    <th>DEP Number</th>
    <th>DEP Title</th>
    <th>DEP Revision Date</th>
    <th>Heading Hierarchy</th>
    <th>Section Item No</th>
    <th>SHALL[PS] Statement</th>
    <th>Requirement Type</th>
    <th>Discipline</th>
    <th>Risk Rating (P)</th>
    <th>Risk Rating (A)</th>
    <th>Risk Rating (C)</th>
    <th>Risk Rating (E)</th>
    </thead>
    </tr>
```

The second foreach loop generates duplicate values

```
#foreach($workitem in $workitems) #set($wiType = $workitem.fields().type().optionId())
<tr>
  <td> $projectId</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>$workitem.fields.docNumber.render </td>
  #if($wiType.equals("document"))
  <td>$workitem.fields().description.render()</td>
  #else
  <td></td>
  #end
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  #if($wiType.equals("requirement"))
  <td>$workitem.fields().description.render()</td>
  #else
  <td></td>
  #end
  <td>$workitem.fields().type().render()</td>
  <td>$workitem.fields.discipline.render</td>
  #foreach($rs in $risks)
  <td>$rs.fields.P.render</td>
  <td>$rs.fields.A.render</td>
  <td>$rs.fields.C.render</td>
  <td>$rs.fields.E.render</td>
  #end
</tr>
#end
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Which duplicate values you are refering to?

Comment: these values 0A
3A
4A
1A

Comment: And where this values are, I can't see ` 0A 3A 4A 1A `in the question.

Comment: these are enumeration values  i m calling them from $rs.fields.P.render() method

Comment: Could plz anyone help me resolve this

Comment: Please share the output which is seeing now and the expected output. Without this I won't be able to help you.